# Catalina not allowing me to read-write from remote host? How to fix?

Tags: catalina, scp

I'm trying to download some files from my remote host using scp and proxyjump, however, I keep getting the dread read-only file system anywhere I try to download my file to... initially I couldn't even touch any files to my directory however I managed to run `killall Finder` and that fixed the latter, however, I still cannot download the necessary files to my directory of choice... does anyone know how to fix this?

```
scp -r -oProxyJump=I R:remote_file localfile
```

The above is what I'm using for downloading a file. Where I is an intermediate host, R is the remote host and remote_file is the directory and localfile is my directory, all I get is:

```
localfile: Read-only file system
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "download to the directory of my choice" where exactly is that?  Can you download to the default *Downloads* directory (`/Users/skidjoe/Downloads`, for example)

Comment: I'm trying to download to /Users/skidjoe/someFile/ ; I've also tried downloading to /Users/skidjoe/Downloads and I get the same error...

Comment: See if this helps:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650

Comment: I see, I have read this post before, but I can't seem to figure out what may be the solution (if any exist?). So I can't write to the newly created hard-disk, is there any way to access/write to the other one (which is not read-only)?

Comment: Got to work! Thanks for the help! Had to go out of my root directory and write to Applications folder!

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved.  Post an answer as to what you did to help others in the future.  I'll upvote to get you some points on the scoreboard!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to move out of my root directory and scp somewhere else (Applications folder in my case).